# "And" meaning "if" or "as long as"

Tags: archaicisms

Can anyone confirm that there is an archaic use of the word "and" meaning "if" or "as long as"? For example:
"Yes you can, and you do no harm."

If you can confirm, please point me to a resource that describes the usage. Thanks.

Comment: That would be an old meaning of *an*, not *and*.   See [M-W.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/an), "an (conjunction)", definition 2.

Comment: Please eliminate the programming reference -- it merely confuses things (and may cause some readers to function check).

Comment: Hellion is correct. Thank you, and apologies to all for the very late response.

Comment: This use of *an* seems to derive from *and*, though, @Hellion. See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600617/1696. (In fact, perhaps this question could be considered a duplicate?)